# Turn: How to suppress STDOUT

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

[Turn](https://github.com/turn-project/turn) shows STDOUT for failed errors messages. Is there any config that will turn it off?

My config:

```
Turn.config do |config|
  config.format = :outline
  config.trace = 5
  config.natural = true
end
```

Comment: Which command are you running? What is the output? Which part exactly do you want to disable? Have you checked https://github.com/turn-project/turn#configuration ?

Comment: Sorry, added my config. The output includes blocks specifically marked "STDOUT" with the output that occurred during the failed test. (It's buffered by turn and output at the end if it fails.)